# Cannot deploy fabcar chaincode on second peer

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to setup multi-host network on my laptop and Jetson Nano.
I managed to setup everything, join both hosts to the same channel and install fabcar chaincode on Host 1(laptop), then I tried to install it on Host 2 from Host 1's CLI and got this Error:

```
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation
of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build
failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "standard_init_linux.go:228: exec
user process caused: no such file or directory"
```

I found out that it's because of architecture difference between hosts (arm64 on Nano and amd64 on laptop VM), but I don't really understand how to resolve this issue. Is it possible to deploy chaincode on hosts with different architectures?

Is there a way to build chaincode image for ARM with docker buildx?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thank you.

###### UPDATE 18.08:

I tried to add CLI on host-2 and then package and install chaincode from there but it failed anyway with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by specifying **fabric-ccenv** image for arm64 in **CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER** variable in **docker-compose.yaml** file under peer container variables. An image i used:

```
- CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=ottoflaherty/fabric-ccenv:arm64-2.3
```